# GAE Datastore client: How to create enforce unique constraint on properties

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using [anom](https://anom.defn.io/) to map with GAE datastore entities. I am searching for a scalable way to implement unique constraint on properties.

So far I am checking with queries before creating new records like this

```
class User(Model):
    ...
    email_id = props.String(indexed=True)
    ...

    def pre_put_hook(self):
        if (not self.id_or_name) and (User.query().where(User.email_id == self.email_id).count() > 0):
            raise IntegrityError(f'Duplicate entry: User.email == {self.email_id}')
```

It doesn't handle race conditions and will not force uniqueness on db level. Is there any way to do it without any race conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [snippet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/master/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.py) from webapp2's repository and modified it for [anom](https://anom.defn.io/)
with a mixin to easy integration into any number of models. Now I can confirm the uniqueness of multiple fields inside a single entity. Of-course this suffers extra reads when creating new records and these fields are not checked for uniqueness when updating. So these fields must not be allowed to be updated or a similar check can be done when updating these fields in particular. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jnoortheen/3b0558368550ea7819f017aca4df5f84). I hope this will be useful when using new Python 3 runtime of GAE and `anom` as data-mapper

Answer (score 2):

There's no great way to do it at the db level besides using 'email' as your primary key do user. You'll be relying on your web application code / ORM (whether it be `anom` or `ndb`) to do the enforcement.

See this answer

[composite key in google cloud datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303734/composite-key-in-google-cloud-datastore/51316235#51316235)

Comment: the problem is that I need to have an id field as well. Also there is more than one unique field in the model like username

Answer (score 1):

The reason for which your current method is still prone to race conditions is the fact that (non-ancestor) query results are always eventually consistent. Even if you use ancestor queries (the only queries allowed inside a transaction) you may still probably be facing race conditions due to the datastore's [Isolation and consistency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/transactions#isolation_and_consistency) model.

As Alex mentions, the only way to ensure uniqueness would be to use the property value as the entity's key identifier (you'd be checking the key's existence in your `pre_put_hook` method, see [TypeError with get_or_insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838726/typeerror-with-get-or-insert/42841696#42841696)). But you can only do that for a single property for an entity kind and in particular for the email address property it'd not be a great idea as it'd be difficult to handle email address changes.

There could be ways of enforcing uniqueness, but allowing a temporary/transient potentially duplicate condition, see [ndb verify entity uniqueness in transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329304/ndb-verify-entity-uniqueness-in-transaction/36334623#36334623).